# Documentation in Xcode requires me to sign and then fails

Tags: xcode, ios4

Before I upgraded Xcode and the iOS SDk to 3.2.5 and 4.2 respectively I could select text in Xcode, right click and and select find text in documentation, and it would go to the corresponding place in the documentation, however now if I do that it asks me to sign in with my apple ID, and then it tells me I'm not authorized? However I can access the documentation in a normal web browser like chrome, it's just irritating to not have the convenience of selecting and right clicking. (NB I'm not a paying developer, but I never have been)

Why is this? Is it only me? and how do I fix it?

Comment: I'm having the same trouble. Very annoying!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a hacky but working fix, inspired by http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tools-utilities/66298-unable-access-sdk-documentation-since-upgrade.html:

Open the file `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_2.iOSLibrary.docset/Contents/Info.plist`

Change the DocSetFallbackURL value from `https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/prerelease` to `http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/`.

Relaunch Xcode, and voilà.

If you open the URL from DocSetFeedURL (in the same Info.plist) in Safari, you can download a .xar file of the documentation. Not sure what that file is, but I'm currently downloading it...

Comment: I had to edit the Info.plist file as root since my user didn't have permissions to change it. But once I made the change described here, it worked.

Comment: just for future reference it's /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS5_0.iOSLibrary.docset/Contents/Info.plist for iOS5

Answer (score 1):

I'm a dev, also, but am blocked from accessing  online documentation with "index.html is locked. Do you want to unlock it?" Type  and it states that the file cannot be unlocked and suggests saving a local copy.

Here's what I see in the .plist file:

https://developer.apple.com/library/etc/redirect/xcode/ios/606

So, in short, access through Safari (inconvenient while working in Xcode-- contextual access not available-- or just download the files as suggested above.

Answer (score -2):

If you're not a paying member of the iOS SDK program, then you can't access the online documentation via Xcode. Since you have the SDK, I would assume you are, so you may just be stumbling over a bug. In any case, you should open up Xcode Preferences and navigate to the Documentation tab (on the far right). By opening up this tab, Xcode will shortly attempt to download the full docsets that you are missing. You can tell this is happening because the right side of the rows will switch to saying "Getting...". You can also open the Activity window (in the Window menu) to see the progress of the download/install.

Comment: I'm part of the free developer program, ie I can't run on devices or put any apps on the appstore, but before I updated I could access the documentation through Xcode just fine. I downloaded Xcode and the iOS4.2 from the Apple developer website after logging in with the same Apple ID.