# XCode 4.2: Organizer documentation is locked in a OSX Lion way

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I'm using the XCode 4.2 beta (build 4D199) on Lion, and can't access the Developer Documentation in XCode 4.2 anymore. When I attempt to log-in, I get a pop-up telling me the (remote) file is "locked", in the fashion that Lion does these things.

Does anybody have a suggestion what I can do to access the documentation from within the Organizer?
I used to be able to access it without any issues, not sure what changed.

[image: Screenshot]
[image: After clicking unlock]

Comment: I got it to work by following the instructions in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352659/documentation-in-xcode-requires-me-to-sign-and-then-fails/4673685#4673685

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The situation was fixed for me by Apple / XCode itself, as it automatically downloaded the (newly available?) "iOS 5.0 Library" documentation files. Documentation now runs from a complete local copy.

To be sure you get this too you need to have the automatic download of documentation files turned on.

`Preferences > Downloads > Documentation > Check for and install updates automatically`

(You can also download the files manually by clicking on "Check and install now")

Answer (score 1):

Same here.
To work around this issue, right click on the sign in page and choose "Open Page in Browser". This will open the same resource in Safari.

Comment: It's been fixed by Apple it seems, see my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

1.- Download library from: http://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone5_0.atom

2.- Open with The Unarchiver

3.- Copy file in "Developer/Documentation/DocSets

4.- Open Xcode

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. To solve it (well seems like that), i went in

Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Documentation

Download the parts you need, for me it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters have stated you should be able to fix these problems by downloading the documentation again.  However, given that a complete set of iOS & MacOS documentation clocks in at around 2.0GB here is an **alternative method that avoids re-downloading**.

Jump to the documentation folder:

`cd /Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets`

Recurse through all the documentation sets and **set the current user as the owner**:

`for f in *.docset; do sudo chown -R $USER $f; done`

**Unlock the documentation sets:**

`for f in *.docset; do SetFile -a l $f; done`

*N.B. Your documentation path may be different (check `~/Library/...`), you should make sure that `$USER` is correctly set to your username, you will need the root password*