# iOS 5 - access to documentation in xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios5, documentation

Why does apple require me to buy the developer fee to access documentation in xcode? I get the following message when I try accessing the documentation within xcode.

> #### You do not have access to this resource based on your membership.
>
> > Access to technical resources such as pre-release software and associated documentation, and information related to distributing iOS or Mac apps on the App Store are benefits offered to Apple Developer Program members.
> >
> > Either the Apple ID and password you entered is not associated with an Apple Developer Program, or the Program that you are enrolled in does not have access to this resource.

Comment: Can you give the link you are trying? I think I received this message more than once for documentation that should be freely available. I have a developer's license, so this seemed odd to me at the time. (I never had this problem from my home office, though.)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how I can give you a link.. but in the far right corner (in xcode), if you click in the Quick Help area on any class, methodName it opens up the documentation window. Thats where I get this message.

Comment: It seems you need to install the docks local.
See this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725506/xcode-4-2-organizer-documentation-is-locked-in-a-osx-lion-way

Comment: Thanks guys.. the option in the preferences to download fixed this problem

Answer (score 0):

You need a developer account to access any of the documentation pertaining to any sort of Apple development. I assume they want you to log in to they can see how many developers are floating around and also so you can authenticate your profile and download the docs from their servers.

If you trying to access documentation that is part of the beta build then you for sure need to purchase and development account versus using the free version, since only paid developers can download, use and distribute their apps.

Comment: hmmm.. not really.. see the link posted by Slappy. Once I downloaded, I can now access all the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this issue, but local docs are installed. Try removing the iOS 5.0 library and adding it again via Preferences-> Documentation. The Base URL changed when iOS 5 was released (no longer pre-release), but the updater doesn't trigger an update of that automatically.