# Invoking Help in Xcode takes me to the Apple Developer's login page which does not allow me to login

Tags: xcode, ios5

iOS 5 library was automatically downloaded to my machine recently.  Since this happened, when I invoke help, I get the Apple Developer's login page.   When I try to log in, the page does not allow me to type anything in the password prompt.   Basically, this is the same problem posted in question [Documentation in Xcode requires me to sign and then fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352659).

I tried to apply the solution listed on that question, but I cannot find file

`/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_2.iOSLibrary.docset/Contents/Info.plist`

Basically, the `Contents` folder indicated at the end of this path is not present on my machine.  Could someone please point me to another possible location for the `info.plist` file, or another solution to this problem?  Otherwise, I am stuck having to check documentation with Safari.  It's much better to have it integrated with Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to manage and install the document sets from Xcode's preferences:

[image: Xcode preferences window for documentation]

Comment: That's what was missing.  Once downloaded it worked.  Thanks.   I thought these had been downloaded already.